# Python, generating PDF using ReportLab.Platypus SimpleDocTemplate, date/time in header

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, reportlab, platypus

I'm working on a project in Python/Django which uses ReportLab's SimpleDocTemplate to generate PDF documents.

All the documents generated have the current date/time printed in the top right corner.  I can't see that it's being done anywhere in my code, is this a default behaviour in the SimpleDocTemplate object?

How do I get rid of this?

Regards,
Haukur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried to reproduce the behavior you described, but unfortunately I cant. So I don't think it's a default behavior. Maybe it would be a good idea if you post a small example where the production date/time in the header is visible.

But if it's any help to you, here is what I've done: I used the following example from the [user guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), which looks like [this](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/178237/). But even when I call doc.build() without the additional arguments, I get no header at all.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I took one more look at this code (I didn't write it originally, so I don't know it very well), I noticed that the doc.build method was taking in a parameter called onFirstpage which was pointing to a custom method I had not noticed before. 

In that method, the document was being initialized and there it was:  The date/time being output in the top right corner.

So, even though you did not answer my question directly, at least your comment made me take a good second look at the code :-)

Thanks!

Comment: He did answer your question.  It is not the default behavior.